# jQuery dialog position when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this javascript/jQuery to open a dialog, however when I scroll down on the page and open another window after closing the first one, the window will open at **my selection position, plus the position I scrolled down.** When I try to move it around, it will keep jumping **down**, causing a very annoying result.

```
function showDialog(url) {

    dialogFrame = $('<iframe style="width:100% !important;" frameborder="0" id="Dialog" src="' + url + '" />').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 500,
        width: 1000,
        title: 'myWindow',
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        position: {
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: window
        }
    });
}
```

How can I prevent this behavior? It's probably the `position : { }` but what should it be?

Comment: Why don't you use fixed position from the top of the screen `position:fixed;`

Comment: That does not fix the drag and drop solution, it's still jumping down.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues with a jQuery UI dialog when the `body` had the CSS property `position:relative;`. You might want to check if that is the case.

In my case I could not remove the `position:relative;` so I decided to override the `top` value and use a fixed positioning:

```
$(".dialogFrame").dialog({
    // ...
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(event.target).parent().css('position', 'fixed');
        $(event.target).parent().css('top', '20px');
    }
    // ...
});
```

The script could be optimized by calculating the effective center of the screen.

Comment: Lovely, there might be other solutions so I'm keeping it open for now.

Comment: When I remember correctly, the problem lies in calculating the top value of the dialog. Could you try `position:['middle',20],` to set the top value explicitly?